# Object & method by name

Tags: java, exception, methods

[ note: i'm beginner in java ]

I try to call object by name and then I try to call its method by name,

but this code throws exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:

```
Field mainClassField = mainObject.getClass()
                                 .getField( dataObject.callObject );
/* callObject is an another object */
Object callObject = mainClassField.get( mainObject );   

Method callMethod = callObject.getClass()
                      .getMethod( dataObject.callMethod ); << error on this line
callMethod.invoke(callObject, dataObject);
```

[ note: i pass dataObject from actionscript 3 through AMF ]

calling object code:

```
public class UserCallController extends Controller {

    public void getUserById(DataTransferObject dataObject) {
        Ppvchat mainClass = _inst._mainClass;

        dataObject.data.put("userData", 
                mainClass.userModel.getById( dataObject.data.getString("id") ));
    }

}
```

thanks.

Comment: Printing the values of the variable (or using a debugger to do it for you) would probably help a lot. (As would some less ambiguous naming. :)) But my suspicion is that you want to pass a parameter to `callMethod`, but in your call to `getMethod()` you ask for a no-parameter method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `NoSuchMethodException` such method indeed does not exist.
So, check the following.

1. what class are you dealing with.
2. what method are you trying to call. Double check the method name and signature.

Anyway your code seems wrong.

`callObject.getClass().getMethod( dataObject.callMethod );` means that you think that method does not have arguments.

`callMethod.invoke(callObject, dataObject);` means that you think that this method has argument assignable from `dataObject`.

Comment: ok, method exist. but i didn't pass parameter to method. it works. thanks guys.